# New version of g++ with an older version of libstdc++

Tags: c++, linux, libstdc++

I am running Linux CentOS 7.3 which comes with g++ 4.8.5. I would like to use g++ 7.1.0 to compile some C++ software. But the C++ program compiled with g++ 7.1.0 is using the headers from the standard library that comes with g++ 7.1.0 and the libstdc++.so which also comes with it which make things really painful.

Is there a way to use g++ 7.1.0 and still use the standard library (both headers and libstdc++.so) from g++ 4.8.5 installed with CentOS?

Comment: Have you tried using `-std=c++03`/`-std=gnu++03` with `-Wl,-rpath` pointing to the original libraries?

Comment: What exactly is painful? You add `-Wl,-rpath=/path/to/your/new/libstdc++.so/directory` to your g++ flags, and you are done.

Comment: @n.m. Let say you want to compile TensorFlow which comes with its own build system such as Bazel and you don't want to spend too much time hacking such a thing. :-(

Comment: Any build system worth its salt ought to respect CFLAGS, CXXFLAGS and LDFLAGS environment variables. You may want to look at [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bazel-discuss/gg8zEdXXUgc) though.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to use g++ 7.1.0 and still use the standard library (both headers and libstdc++.so) from g++ 4.8.5 installed with CentOS?

Don't do that (the ABI of `libstdc++` from GCC 4.8 & GCC 7 are likely to be different). Instead consider perhaps linking the C++ standard library (from GCC 7.1) *statically* (and other libraries dynamically, notably those in C including `libc.so`, not C++).

BTW, how did you get  `g++-7.1`? You could consider compiling GCC 7 (from its source code) on your CentOS 7 (or get some packaged version of it), then you'll have the right `libstdc++`

Read more about shared libraries, e.g. read Drepper's paper [*How To Write Shared Libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) and learn more about the `-rpath` option passed to `ld` (often using `-Wl,-rpath` to `g++`).

Comment: I would like to build shared libraries with g++-7.1 and then link some programs built with g++-7.1 with those libraries and at the same time with libraries that come from CentOS. So I guess that static linking is not an option.
I have compiled g++-7.1 on this machine. I need it to get better auto-vectorization for some programs.

Comment: By the way, it it is an ABI problem, would it be fine if the program was in C and not C++?

Comment: Yes, a pure C program has much less ABI sensitivity to C standard library version

Comment: Thanks. That's too bad it is not possible to use different ABI with a given version of the compiler. The Intel compiler is smart enough to use the ABI of the g++ you have on your system or any version of g++ that you can give it to him.

Comment: Are you sure of that? Did you try to use `icc` with the *headers* of your newer `libstdc++` ? And do you really need `icc` ? Can't you comple all your thing with the *same* `g++`

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the ABI depends mostly on the version of the C++ standard you are using. If you use -std=c++03 for example, you will be able to run your binary in systems where the available libstdc++ is older. Otherwise, you would completely break backwards compatibility. Usually the headers have appropriate preprocessor conditional blocks either use the new or the old implementations. Remember that GCC 5 uses C++03, GCC 6 uses C++11 and GCC 7 uses C++17 by default.

Comment: @Basile That's what they claim: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522750 . Anyway, the same version of icpc works with distributions that comes with g++ 4.8 and others with g++ 5.4

Comment: @Jorge: They broke the implementation of things such as std::string from gcc 4.x to gcc 5.x anyway. So I am not sure that this is only a matter of C++ version. But to be honest, I have no idea if std::string is in the signature of some functions in libstdc++

Comment: "and at the same time with libraries that come from CentOS" If these are C++ libraries, this *may* prove a bit problematic. You may have to switch to the old C++ ABI with your program. C libraries are no problem.

Comment: @n.m. That was the point of my question (although it was not very clear to me at first). Is there a way to use the ABI of g++ 4.8.5 with g++ 7.1.0. With intel compilers, with a given version of the compiler you can choose different ABI versions of gcc.

Comment: @InsideLoop Yes, you can use `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` to switch g++>=5 (or rather libstdc++ that comes with it) to the old ABI. You may or may not need it. If you don't plan to e.g. pass `std::string` and `std::list` between modules compiled with different versions of g++, then chances are you don't need it.

Comment: @n.m. Another question related. I have binary packages (say Anaconda Python distribution which comes with a lot of C/C++ libraries) that link dynamically with libstdc++.so of my system and that can install on both systems with g++-4.8 and g++-5.4. How come it is possible?

Comment: @InsideLoop there is backward compatibility. Programs using the old ABI can run on a system with a newer libstdc++ because it supports both the new and the old ABI.

Answer (score 3):

The libstdc++ ABI [changed](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html#libstdcxx) between gcc4 and gcc5 so that's not going to work. If you are using gcc7 you should install libstdc++ 7. You can have both versions installed at the same time

Comment: You can only have one `libstdc++.so.6` as the system library. Parallel installation requires playing games with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Answer (score 3):

Developer Toolset is designed for this scenario, but it is currently at GCC version 6:

- https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-6/

Its C++ compiler has been configured in such a way that the programs it compiles are linked dynamically against the system `libstdc++`, using a backwards-compatible ABI, and only the library code for new C++ features not yet supported by the system library is linked statically.  This gives maximum compatibility and allows compiled applications to run without DTS.